# Saving Cubemap to file and load it in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, save

I am trying to save cupemap object in unity and load it to perform a SAVE/LOAD function in my application so I tried this code to save my cubemap and it works fine :

```c#
foreach (var gameObj in FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[])
{
    if (gameObj.name.StartsWith("Chambre"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Chambre " + (l + 1), gameObj.name);
        var chambre = new Material(Shader.Find("Skybox/Cubemap"));
        chambre = gameObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
        var Texture1 = chambre.GetTexture("_Tex");

        if (!AssetDatabase.Contains(Texture1))
        {
            AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(Texture1, "Assets/Resources/Saved/chambre" + (l + 1) + ".mat");
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
            AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        }

        l++;
    }
}
```

But the problem here that I use the import UnityEditor which is not accepted when you try to build the game. So is there another solution to save my cubemap and reload it without using "AssetDatabase.CreateAsset" because it called by UnityEditor?

Comment: Could you use local store? like JSON files? If yes, I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: yes i use local store

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you want to archive.
In a build there are no "Assets" anymore so the methods make no sence in a build.

To use them in the Editor anyway and be able to build your code you just have to use pre-processors `#if UNITY_EDITOR <your code> #endif` arround code blocks that shall only exist in the Editor:

```c#
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    using UnityEditor;
#endif

...

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    foreach (var gameObj in FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[])
    {
        if (gameObj.name.StartsWith("Chambre"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Chambre " + (l + 1), gameObj.name);
            var chambre = new Material(Shader.Find("Skybox/Cubemap"));
            chambre = gameObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
            var Texture1 = chambre.GetTexture("_Tex");

            if (!AssetDatabase.Contains(Texture1))
            {
                AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(Texture1, "Assets/Resources/Saved/chambre" + (l + 1) + ".mat");
                AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
                AssetDatabase.Refresh();
            }

            l++;
        }
    }

#endif
```

So those codeblocks will not be included/executed in your build.

Comment: Ok , i tried this before but i want to execute my code .. so i should find a solution to save my cubemap texture in another to file without using UnityEditor import... that's means i should save mycubemap to file without unisng the method "AssetDatabase.CreateAsset"